# How to use ElectronJS's screen.dipToScreenPoint() method?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am tying to use the `screen.dipToScreenPoint()` method.
As mentioned in [Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/screen#screendiptoscreenpointpoint-windows), but I'm getting the undefined method error. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: post a code snippet please, to determine the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was using old version moving to the latest V8.0.0 fixed the problem